# Is it possible to apply RTAI patch to Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, real-time, rtos

I want to build a real-time version of linux. I am wondering if it worth trying to apply RTAI patch to android. Can any experience programmer shed some light ?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-kernel@googlegroups.com/msg00719.html) should answer your question. Sounds like it's not really worth trying.

Comment: I have already gone through that thread. It may not be worth it yet but the problem I am working on is a research problem.